# Complex query with many joins

Tags: mysql, django, group-by, inner-join

I am trying to make one query, to get some statistic data from database.

My tables structure described here:

```
PRODUCTS
id | price | buy_price | vendor_code | ...

ORDERS
id | shipping_method_id | ...

ORDER_ITEMS
id | order_id | product_id | quantity | ...

SHIPPING_METHODS
id | cost | ...

SUPPLIERS
id | code | ...
```

I want to get data like this. In words, I am making reports on Product total income, expenses and quantity of buys in my ecommerce, and want them to group by supplier. I wrote this sql:

```
SELECT orders.id,
suppliers.code,
COUNT(products.id)*items.quantity buys,
SUM(products.price*items.quantity + shipping_methods.cost) sales,
SUM(products.buy_price*items.quantity) expenses
FROM `orders` orders
INNER JOIN `order_items` items ON items.order_id = orders.id
INNER JOIN `products` products ON items.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT suppliers.code FROM `suppliers`) suppliers
    ON products.vendor_code LIKE CONCAT(suppliers.code, '%%')
INNER JOIN `shipping_methods` shipping_methods ON orders.shipping_method_id = shipping_methods.id
WHERE (
    orders.delivery_date_to BETWEEN '2011-11-18' AND '2011-11-19'
)
GROUP BY suppliers.code, orders.id
ORDER BY buys DESC
```

this returns to me this data:

```
order_id    code    buys    sales   expenses
85          SB      4       1504    1111.32
84          VD      2       496     350.82
60          lg      2       1418    1052.31
88          SB      1       376     277.83
```

When I change `GROUP BY suppliers.code, orders.id` to `GROUP BY suppliers.code`, it returns almost correct data, I mean data is grouped by code, but counting is wrong. Admit that sales and expenses are correct

```
order_id    code    buys    sales   expenses
85          SB      8       1880    1389.15
60          lg      2       1418    1052.31
84          VD      2       496     350.82
```

If u see SB counted total 8 sales, but really there are only 5, as u can see in previous table. I'm sure I missed something in my query, but cant understand how to correct this.

PS field order_id are unused in my further scripts, I use it because django's Model.objects.raw() query does need to have primary key in result, don't really understand why

Comment: are all the relations between tables safe? is there any chance there are some records in suppliers table which are not linked to orders?

Comment: In fact, suppliers table are not related to orders. There is field `code`, and in products table `vendor_code` that starts with that code. Example, my products vendor_code are SB3418335, VDLC258810-8 and so on

Comment: the problem is there are two individual orders (order_id 85 and 88). if you want to see total count, you should first get rid of order_id column. this query wouldn't work for MSSQL for example. when you do grouping like that, you should exclude these fields. but still, it's not the solution of your problem. You may try to use this whole query with GROUP BY suppliers.code, orders.id as an innerSQL and make a second GROUP BY suppliers.code in the outter SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query.

```
SELECT t1.code, SUM(t1.buys), SUM(t1.sales) FROM (
SELECT orders.id, 
suppliers.code, 
COUNT(products.id)*items.quantity buys, 
SUM(products.price*items.quantity + shipping_methods.cost) sales, 
SUM(products.buy_price*items.quantity) expenses 
FROM `orders` orders 
INNER JOIN `order_items` items ON items.order_id = orders.id 
INNER JOIN `products` products ON items.product_id = products.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT suppliers.code FROM `suppliers`) suppliers 
    ON products.vendor_code LIKE CONCAT(suppliers.code, '%%') 
INNER JOIN `shipping_methods` shipping_methods ON orders.shipping_method_id = shipping_methods.id 
WHERE ( 
    orders.delivery_date_to BETWEEN '2011-11-18' AND '2011-11-19' 
) 
GROUP BY suppliers.code, orders.id 
ORDER BY buys DESC 
) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.code
```

Edit: I've forgotten SUM() parts. Just added, please retry if you've already tried.

Comment: This one works! Thanks, I've already tried, before you write this post. Anyway, everything is the same, expect aliases.